# YA Sci Fi Alternate universe/reality where all cars are black

Tags: parallel-universe

I read this book between 2007-2012. I believe that the protagonist travels to an alternate universe where there are small differences between the two worlds. In particular, I remember that all of the cars were black, which was surprising to him. Sadly that's all I can really remember and I know this is pretty vague. :(

Comment: Crossposted to http://forums.abebooks.com/discussions/AbeBookscom_BookSleuthreg/Science_Fiction/YA_Sci_Fi_Alternate_universereality_where_all_cars_are_black/abesleuthcom/39004.1?redirCnt=1&nav=messages&mobile=y but no answer yet.